Fail to install Python 3.10 using pyenv, installer says ncurses, readline, and OpenSSL are used from brew but failed to compile
I am installing Python 3.10 using pyenv, but installer throw error saying that dependencies are not compiled. However, installer also says that python-build use openssl, readline, and ncurses from homebrew.
CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun -show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib"
 pyenv install 3.10
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.10.15.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.15/Python-3.10.15.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.10.15...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use ncurses from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/quan.nguyen/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/lib/python3.10/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
WARNING: The Python curses extension was not compiled. Missing the ncurses lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/quan.nguyen/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 99, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (OS X 15.0 using python-build 2.4.13)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/f_/_mwchwz12xzbycp94nqvbdv5s9_ljk/T/python-build.20240919150807.79066
Results logged to /var/folders/f_/_mwchwz12xzbycp94nqvbdv5s9_ljk/T/python-build.20240919150807.79066.log

Last 10 log lines:
            $ensurepip --root=/ ; \
    fi
Looking in links: /var/folders/f_/_mwchwz12xzbycp94nqvbdv5s9_ljk/T/tmpklg5hx7t
Processing /private/var/folders/f_/_mwchwz12xzbycp94nqvbdv5s9_ljk/T/tmpklg5hx7t/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /private/var/folders/f_/_mwchwz12xzbycp94nqvbdv5s9_ljk/T/tmpklg5hx7t/pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
  WARNING: The scripts pip3 and pip3.10 are installed in '/Users/quan.nguyen/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  NOTE: The current PATH contains path(s) starting with `~`, which may not be expanded by all applications.
Successfully installed pip-23.0.1 setuptools-65.5.0

❯ pyenv doctor
Cloning /Users/quan.nguyen/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-doctor/bin/.....
Installing python-pyenv-doctor...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use ncurses from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 15.0 using python-build 2.4.13)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/f_/_mwchwz12xzbycp94nqvbdv5s9_ljk/T/python-build.20240919153937.2140
Results logged to /var/folders/f_/_mwchwz12xzbycp94nqvbdv5s9_ljk/T/python-build.20240919153937.2140.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for rl_gnu_readline_p in -lreadline... no
configure: error: GNU readline is not installed.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Problem(s) detected while checking system.

See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems for known solutions.

I have tried looking into Common build problems page and added flags per the instruction. I don't know where else to look into.

I think OS X 15.0 is just out? So do expect problems with various external tools, including some Homebrew libraries. Have you updated all your Homebrew libraries?
